# Python | Expecting type INT, but if STR entered?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input, integer

I'm asking the user for an integer type input. But if the user accidentally inputs string type, I want it to tell the use they incorrectly answer the question. Like this:

```
question1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if question1 != int:
    print("Please enter a number.")
else:
     ...
```

Please note I am a beginner, and therefore do not understand expect style coding.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In your `if` statement you are comparing `question1`, an integer, with `int`, a type. They will never be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a `string` to an `integer` will only work if the string looks like an integer.

Anything else will raise a `ValueError`.

My suggestion is to catch this `ValueError` and inform the user appropriately.

```
try:
    question1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a number!")
else:
    print("Congratulations - you followed the instructions")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.isdigit()` method to check if the input contains digits only

```
question1 = input("Enter a number: ")
if question1.isdigit():
    question1= int(question1)
else:
     print("Not a number")
```